# How to execute shell script from flask every n minutes?

Tags: python, bash, flask

I have a simple bash script `switch.sh` in my working dir that I need to run every n minutes in my flask app.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger
from subprocess import call

def run_aws_script():
    call(". ./switch-role.sh", shell=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_aws_script()

    scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
    scheduler.start()
    scheduler.add_job(func=run_aws_script,
        trigger=IntervalTrigger(minutes=25),
        id='Switching role',
        name='Switch role every 25 minutes',
        replace_existing=True)

    app.run()
```

If I start my program from my working dir where is `aws-switch-role` located like: `python app.py` everything is working fine.

But If I run it from another dir like `python server/app.py` I have
`/bin/sh: ./switch-role.sh: No such file or directory`

How can I fix that?

I want to run that script before my app start.
How can I remove first call `run_aws_script()` and move it to the `scheduler`?

Comment: Typically you'd do this using something like cron. How are you hosting your application?

Comment: run script with full path; you currently do with . or change dir to one where the script is before calling it

Comment: @Chris Is it bad idea to use subprocess? Could you explain why?

Comment: @Drako Can you provide a code how can i run script with full path?

Comment: @petrush, subprocess only does part of what you're looking for. It runs a process. But it doesn't have any scheduling functionality. Cron does both.

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully python documentation, then you can find information that using "shell=True" is not secure. You can use subprocess.check_output command, instead of call.

```
cwd = <path_to_switch_role.sh>
subprocess.check_output([cwd],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

in this case there is no mater from which directory you run those python.
And about this run every n minutes, you can use python sleep command.